# Can anyone help me to pass data fetched from mysql database in a table to another page on submit?

Tags: php, mysql

I am developing an eCommerce site for books.When user search for specific book category then the books related that category is fetched from database using php and mysql and shown in a table with **buy now** button.When user click on buy button for specific ISBN number then it is redirected to purchase page where user has to give his/her billing info for selected ISBN number.But the problem is that On clicking Buy Now button that particular ISBN is not passed in purchase page.
Here is my **searchresult.php** code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">                                               <head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title></title>
</head>

<body>
<table class="table table-condensed" style="margin-bottom:0px">
                <thead>
                    <tr class="cart_menu">
                    <td class="image"></td>                    
                        <td class="description">Book Name</td>
                        <td class="description">ISBN Number</td>
                        <td class="description">Price</td>
                        <td></td>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>

                <?php
@$query=("SELECT * from book where category='computer science'");
@$res=mysql_query($query);

while(@$row=mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) { ?>
                    <tr>

                        <td class="cart_description">
                            <h5><?php echo $row['name'] ?></h5>
                                                        </td>
                        <td class="cart_description">
                            <h5><?php echo $row['ISBN'] ?></h5>

                        </td>
                        <td class="cart_description">
                            <h5>$<?php echo $row['price'] ?></h5>

                        </td>
                                                <td>
        <?php echo'<a class="btn btn-primary" name="ISBN" style="margin-top:0px;" href="cart.php?ISBN=' . $row['ISBN'] . '">Buy Now</a>';?>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                     <?php } ?>

                    </tbody></table>
</body>
</html>
```

When user **click on Buy Now button** It is redirected to **cart.php**

Where I am fetching action data from **searchresult.php** i.e ISBN number as:

```
<?php echo $_GET['ISBN']; ?>
```

But after reLoading page the ISBN number is vanished.

Please help me to pass ISBN number and store there till the purchase of book is complete.

Comment: `after refreshing page` - what page are you talking about?

Comment: does the ISBN appear in the link? do you see it on the url of cart.php?

Comment: side notes. stop using mysql_* , its deprecated and will be removed. and never use @ to suppress errors

Comment: Yes I see ISBN on the url of cart.php but when the page is refreshed it is vanished.

Comment: I am talking about cart.php  * after refreshing page

Comment: why\how are you refreshing it?

Comment: *ahem* - Look at this very carefully `?ISBN Number=` and you're doing `$_GET['ISBN']`. Where does `name="vnumber"` come into play?

Comment: As I have mentioned, please make me understand the connection between searchresult.php and cart.php because when customer click on buy now button then all the details of  book chosen by customer to buy should be passed to cart.php page to finish purhase.

Comment: ohhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh well im dumb this morning

Comment: Is it morning there already? @Dagon

Comment: @Fred-ii- yup its work time (giggle)

Comment: why\how are you refreshing it? –  Dagon After user fill out their shipping address and click on finish button.

Comment: i dont think you mean *refresh*

Comment: Hey... @Dagon where'd ya go?

Comment: refresh mean suppose user left some data to fill and clicked on finish button then in that case ISBN no. showed blank

Comment: @MarkHogge that's not a refresh. *refresh* is re-loading the current page (f5 on most browsers)

Comment: Please anyone let me know in detail and gave me the proper code for that.

Comment: @MarkHogge fred answerd this above

Comment: Yes Dagon you said correct i.e reloading

Comment: and now, for *the big gun* - Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything.
 Also add `or die(mysql_error())` to `mysql_query()`.

Comment: Hi Fred it is still not working with what you have provided me answer

Comment: Actually I have done form validation in cart.php using php and form action is <form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>" style="margin:15px;"> s that reason ISBN number is vanished after page reload. Is yes then what is the solution for that please provide.

Comment: Please someone help me to my question.

Answer (score 0):

As people are commenting, I think you used the word refresh incorrectly.  If you want to keep the items in the cart in GET or POST variables that your choice.  I personally think its crazy, you should should be putting them in a table somewhere.  What happens when someone jumps to the contact page by manually typing....everything is going to be gone?

Regardless, if you are losing the ISBN, simply output it as a hidden form input. Then when they submit the form on the cart page it will be posted along with it.  You can also use $_REQUEST to allow for both post and get variables.

mysql_query is depriciated.  You need to stop using it, pdo or mysqli are your options.

Comment: Yes I did it but still I am losing ISBN AFTER PAGE RELOAD. How can I store it regardless of page reload?

Comment: If the variable is still in the url then you didn't lose it.  If the variable is not in the url any more then you aren't reloading you are doing something else (sounds like you are posting).  If you are posting then you can send the data in a hidden form input like I said before.  Seriously though, I think you are way off track with this entire approach,

Comment: Actually I have done form validation in cart.php using php and form action is <form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>" style="margin:15px;"> s that reason ISBN number is vanished after page reload. Is yes then what is the solution for that please provide.

Comment: Yes you have understood my problem correctly.Please provide me solution with full code.

Comment: Its not a joke Seriously I am in trouble with this issue. Please! read it carefully and then pls provide me sln Actually I have done form validation in cart.php using php and form action is <form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>" style="margin:15px;"> s that reason ISBN number is vanished after page reload. Is yes then what is the solution for that please provide.

Comment: No, the reason is when you submit a form you change the url so the $_GET variables are lost...if you store them in an input field `<input type="hidden" name="ISBN" value="<?php echo $_REQUEST["ISBN"]; ?>"> you can pass them along.  Honestly though this is just the first of 10 million problems you are going to encounter and its pretty clear you don't understand what you are doing.  If you are really going to do this you need to read tutorials on how to build an ecommerce/cart system.

Comment: Yes Hendr actually I am a beginner and trying to develop eCommerce site .Will you provide me source where I can master in live project development.If you would give me some suggestion for development then I shall be very much grateful to you.

Comment: If you wont mine where did you learnt from?Actually can you provide exact source. Will you guide me to develop website in php. My email Id is markhogge8@gmail.com

Comment: I can't, I have a full time job.  Google is your friend.